# Android LinkedIn does not work on device and works fine on emulator

Tags: android, oauth, linkedin-api

I have to do LinkedIn integration in my Android app. I have done integration using the sample given on Google Code and tried to post update. It given me access to post network updates denied message. So I found some similar questions on forum and extracted the linked in jar and then re-packaged after editing LinkedInAppUrls.properties file. Here it generates the Access Token and when creating the LinkedInApiClient it throws me VerifyError. However I stopped further steps and removed the LinkedInApiClient creation and run the same app on Device. It gives me

```
OAuthException: Communication with OAuth service failed
```

I don't know what is the problem but tried by clearing cache, cookies everything on browser. Still I am unable to get rid of this OAuthException, how do I do it?. The App works fine with same code on Emulator.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite strange issue on LinkedIn and even Twitter too. They will throw OAuthException when time is wrong. On My Emulator as it takes time of my pc by default it worked but not on device. The reason my device is late by 2 minutes. It is quite strange but it worked when i added that 2 minutes of time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this api for linkedIn. It helps me to post status and get contacts.

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/